# Correct way of saying "graphological" in stylistic analysi

Tags: word-choice

Reading the wikipedia page for graphemics, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphemics I stumble across

"later some scholars suggested calling it graphology[1] to match phonology, but that name is traditionally used for a pseudo-science."

So currently, I am attempting "graphological" analysis of a poem, in a stylistic sense. However, I want to steer away from the pseudo-science term, and I am not sure how to convert 'graphemics' to a 'graphological' equivalent so that I can write

"The poem contains graphological deviation".

I hope I am clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphology is the pseudo-science of deducing personality characteristics from handwriting.  This is the meaning I would assume and I would be puzzled by your intended phrase:  "Does he mean he wrote it with a back-slope?" I would recommend sticking with graphemics.

I avoid applying for jobs where they ask for a specimen of my handwriting as I assume that any company that believes in nonsense like this probably has even more crazy HR policies than the norm.  And the norm is quite crazy enough.